# Customize project context menu of visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 with some add-ins and extensions. The problem is now that the context menu of the project items in the solution explorer is getting so large that I always have to scroll down for the "Properties" and the "Open in Windows Explorer" which I use most.
This is getting very nasty.

Is there a possibility to group commands into a sub menu or to modify the position of the commands in the context menu?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes, it can be edited.

- Go to 'Tools' -> 'Customize...' -> and select the 'Command' tab.
- Select *Context Menu* and pick *Project and Solution Context Menus | Project*

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. I already tried this but if I select the conext menu You described the "Controls:" list is empty; and if I try to add a command to that context menu then visual studio crashes.

Comment: Ouch, that's not normal.  Sounds like you exceeded some internal limit.  Try resetting it and putting things back one step at a time.

Comment: There exists an internal limit!? Anyway, I started Visual Studio now in SafeMode and it worked. Thanks for your answer

Comment: @Manfred Ramoser, I had the same problem here. Thanks for solution.

Comment: Helped me to get rid of maybe 100 superfluous entries in the menu (both duplicates and things I don't need). No longer scrolling for ten seconds to find a certain menu entry...

Answer (score 2):

You can always use the keyboard to do the work for you.

- The default binding for Properties is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (or sometimes <kbd>F4</kbd> depending on what add-ins you have installed). Select the project in Solution Explorer and hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to show it's properties. (This works for almost any other object as well, btw).
- The default binding for view SolutionExplorer is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, so you don't have to use your mouse to get there.
- There is no default binding for opening a project in Windows Explorer, but you can set one yourself.

The keyboard bindings are set under **Tools**->**Options...**->**Environment**->**Keyboard**, and the interesting settings in this case are probably *View.SolutionExplorer*, *Project.OpenFolderinWindowsExplorer* and *View.PropertiesWindow* or *Project.Properties* depending on which propertiy collection you were referring to.

Comment: Hello, thanks for Your answer. I know that I could use shortcuts and I already created my own toolbar where this two commands are present but the "mess" in the context menu of the project still exists and I would like to get rid of that.