# How to find name of context menu in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, editor, contextmenu

I want to change context menus in my Visual Studi 2010. I know how to do that (for example from this post [Customize project context menu of visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184351/customize-project-context-menu-of-visual-studio)), but I don't know how to identify name of context menu to change. There are hundreds context menus and I need to find what context menu opens when I click RMB on particualar editor. Is there any method to find that?

Answer (score 1):

May be the explanation provided in the following link can help you to identify the GUID and ID for the controls, menu items you need. It works for me on VS 2010. If the registry key does not exist, create a new Dword.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dr._ex/archive/2007/04/17/using-enablevsiplogging-to-identify-menus-and-commands-with-vs-2005-sp1.aspx

Cheers,
Nanda